# Data Studio Report not Downloading Properly

Tags: pdf, download, looker-studio

Until today I have been able to download data studio reports as pdfs and, with the exception of some content errors, it has always worked as expected. Now, rather than downloading as a pdf, the report opens as a pdf looking file with a blob:https:/ /datastudio.google.com/4138d etc. URL which according to Chrome is an insecure connection. Trying to download this file results in a "Network Error"

[page that I get when selecting download as pdf](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9AO1S.png)

I have tried checking for malware on Chrome and cannot see anything wrong. I have also restarted my PC and refreshed data studio.

Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think I found a fix though so you can download Data Studio reports in Chrome.

- Click the 3 dots next to your photo in chrome (right under the 'X' button on windows)
- Go to 'Settings'
- Select 'Privacy and Security' from the left side menu
- Select 'Site Settings' from the presented menu
- Under the 'Content' section, select 'Additional content settings'
- Click 'PDF documents'
- Click the 'Download PDFs' button

Changing this setting will download PDFs directly to your downloads folder without opening a separate PDF window in Chrome. To make sure your downloads folder is the default folder click 'Advanced' on the left side menu then click 'Downloads'. You can change your download location from here or turn on the option to have Chrome ask where to save with each download request.

Also, downloading the reports with another browser will work too. I did not have any issues downloading reports with Firefox.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @wilburforcethebrave - all dashboards were downloading without an issue until yesterday and now receiving intermittent errors such as "blob:https:/ /datastudio.google.com/4138d"
Printing the dashboard as a PDF is helpful if the report is one page, but does not work for multiple pages.

Comment: This is happening for me as well when download text/plain or text/csv files. Use to download the file, but now opens blob:// within the browser. Have you found any solution?

Answer (score -1):

I have been having the same issue with this today, and have found a work around. Instead of downloading it in the new tab that opens, click the print button instead. From the print menu, change the printer to "Save as PDF", and it should be able to save as normal. Not sure why we had this issue but this seemed to allow us to download it as a PDF.

Answer (score -1):

I do not have any problem when I export multiple pages dashboard and print as pdf. I suggest you may want to check your pdf print driver within the browser itself.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).